# how to save/upload my result as json file into the sub folders of S3 bucket via python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a dictionary as:

```
My_dict is: 

{'folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_1.csv': 'value_1',
 'folder_1/folder_4/folder_5/file_2.csv': 'value_2'}
```

I would like to add a json file to each folder in S3 which has the `file_1.csv` and `file_2.csv` so that the file name will be called `value.json` including the full path and the corresponding 'value' (i.e `{'folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_1.csv': 'value_1'}`).

I would like to have a `value.json` file in the S3 folders:

1. `folder_1/folder_2/folder_3`
2. `folder_1/folder_4/folder_5`

and each folder should have the 'value.json' as

1. `value.json`: `{'folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_1.csv':'value_1'}`
2. `value.json`: `{'folder_1/folder_2/folder_5/file_2.csv': 'value_2'}`

I am new to AWS S3 and I have tried:

```python
    for file, h_val in My_dict.items():
        s3.put_object(
            Bucket=bucket_name, Body=json.dumps(My_dict), Key=f"{file.replace('.csv','')}.json"
        )
```

but this saves same file in each folder and with both results. However, I would like to have the json file in each folder by just having its own file name and the corresponding value.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet uses `os.path.dirname()` to turn a filename like `folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_1.csv` into `folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/value.json`. It also creates a temporary dictionary value for the content of that particular `value.json` file.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os.path
import json

My_dict = {
    'folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/file_1.csv': 'value_1',
    'folder_1/folder_4/folder_5/file_2.csv': 'value_2'
}

for fname, h_val in My_dict.items():
    print("{} => {}/value.json".format(fname, os.path.dirname(fname)))
    value_json = {fname: h_val}
    print("  {}".format(json.dumps(value_json)))
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Body=json.dumps(value_json),
        Key="{}/value.json".format(os.path.dirname(fname))
    )
```

The `print` calls are for clarification only, of course. This answer will only work if, in practice, there is only ever *one* occurrence of the sub-folders like `folder_1/folder_2/folder_3` in `My_dict`. If there are multiple, with `file_X.csv` entries, only the last `value.json` will be the one that remains.